# How to create a screenshot of a JFace Dialog for printing?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I'm currently working on a eclipse plugin which shows the user a table of entries.

If the user double-clicks on a tablerow, a custom JFace-Dialog is opened in which the user can either print or cancel the dialog.

How can I create a screenshot of the dialog as an image?

My attemp at the moment gives me just a small rectangle.

```
    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(this.getShell(), SWT.NONE);
    PrinterData data = dialog.open();
    if(data == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    GC gc = new GC(this.getShell().getDisplay());
    final Image image = new Image(this.getShell().getDisplay(), this.getShell().getBounds());
    gc.copyArea(image, this.getShell().getBounds().x, this.getShell().getBounds().y);
    gc.dispose();

    Printer printer = new Printer(data);
    if(printer.startJob("Print"))
    {

        GC g = new GC(printer);

        if(printer.startPage())
        {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        g.dispose();
        printer.endPage();


    }
    printer.endJob();
    printer.dispose();
```

Comment: Does the created `Image` contain the whole area?

Comment: The image contains a small area of the opened PrinterDialog but I thought creating the image before would prevent this behaviour.

Comment: What I meant is: Does the actual `Image` instance that you create (called `image`) contain the whole area? The one you use to draw on the printer?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes it does.

Comment: Oh sorry, I found the problem, stupid me :D
I should create the image first and not the PrinterDialog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order. The image should be created first.
I didn't recognize that the screenshot size was right, but covered with the PrinterDialog.

```
GC gc = new GC(this.getShell().getDisplay());
final Image image = new Image(this.getShell().getDisplay(),this.getShell().getBounds());
gc.copyArea(image, this.getShell().getBounds().x, this.getShell().getBounds().y);
gc.dispose();    

PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(this.getShell(), SWT.NONE);
PrinterData data = dialog.open();
if(data == null)
{
    return;
}

Printer printer = new Printer(data);
if(printer.startJob("Print"))
{

    GC g = new GC(printer);

    if(printer.startPage())
    {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }

    g.dispose();
    printer.endPage();


}
printer.endJob();
printer.dispose();
```